# Printing only once IF statement

Tags: php, javascript, html

Below is a php file used within my e-commerce website (prototype) to write the item(s) selected by a customer and storing their choices in a flat file database. The logic works fine although the `echo "Order Submitted!;` is printed for every item selected e.g. if 4 items are selected this line is printed 4 times, I only require it to be printed once. Any idea how this could be accomplished?

```
<body>

    <table>

        <?php   
        if (!($data = file('items.txt'))) {
            echo 'ERROR: Failed to open file! </body></html>';
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "<h1>Transaction Completed!</h1>"; 
        }
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $now = date(' d/m/y H:i:s ');
        $visitor = $_POST['visitor']; 

        foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {
                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                if ($partno == $varname) {
                    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
                    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("ERROR: Failed to open purchases file!\n");
                    $content = $now . "|" . $visitor . "|" . $partno . "|" . $name . "|" . $price . "\n";

                    if (!(fwrite($fh, $content))) {
                        echo "<p>ERROR: Cannot write to file($myFile)\n</p>";
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
                        fclose($fh);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>

    </table>

    <input type="button" onClick="parent.location='home.php'" value="Return Home">
    <input type="button" onClick="parent.location='items.php'" value="New Purchase">
```

If 2 items are selected the output is:

**Transaction Completed
Order Submitted!
Order Submitted!**

Comment: *" flat file database"*... there are e-commerce websites that use flat file databases?

Comment: Before your first foreach, create a var like `$numdisplayed = 0;` and then before the order submitted, change `} else {` to `} else {\nif (!$numdisplayed++)`

Comment: It's a project it's not designed to be used in the real world

Comment: Like this? } else {\nif (!$numdisplayed++)
                            echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
                            fclose($fh);

Comment: I've tried @MarkOrmston answer however I get Fatal error: Call to undefined function nif() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ebassignment\write.php on line 34

Comment: @JeffShaver using a file database isn't usefull in any case except for learning how to work with files. otherwise you won't be able to just change on variable or something and then use a full blown database instead of the filedatabase tue to the lack of objectoriented programming.

Comment: @ITroubs then say that? That is much better than laughing in his face and telling him he should be fired. It was just kind of unnecessary IMO.

Comment: @JeffShaver ever tried to correct errors such people produced? this task looks like a problem some one should attemt to solve who has some kind of experience. Otherwise the next guy to work on that project will be in big trouble..

Comment: I can't do carriage returns in comments... I meant the \n to be a new line, not literally \n ...

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of if there's an error and move the else outside the loop.

```
$error=false;
    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
        foreach ($data as $thedata) {
            list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
            if ($partno == $varname) {
                $myFile = "purchases.txt";
                $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("ERROR: Failed to open purchases file!\n");
                $content = $now . "|" . $visitor . "|" . $partno . "|" . $name . "|" . $price . "\n";

                if (!(fwrite($fh, $content))) {
                    echo "<p>ERROR: Cannot write to file($myFile)\n</p>";
                    $error=true;
                    exit;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
if(!$error) {
  echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
  fclose($fh);
}
```

Although, the way you have it written, you don't even need a conditional surrounding "Order submitted" because it will never execute if there's an error. (Due to the exit.)

Also you can move $myfile out of the loop if it doesn't change.

Second version:

```
    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
        foreach ($data as $thedata) {
            list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
            if ($partno == $varname) {
                $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("ERROR: Failed to open purchases file!\n");
                $content = $now . "|" . $visitor . "|" . $partno . "|" . $name . "|" . $price . "\n";

                if (!(fwrite($fh, $content))) {
                    echo "<p>ERROR: Cannot write to file($myFile)\n</p>";
                    exit;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
  echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
  fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

before foreach loop:

```
$printed=false;
```

then instead of

```
else {
    echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
    fclose($fh);
}
```

use

```
else {
    if(!$printed)
    {
        echo "<p>Order Submitted!</p>";
        $printed=true;
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `echo` from the `else` branch and put it right after the first `foreach` closing bracket

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter and see if more the one was submitted

like:

```
$count=0;
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue) {
            foreach ($data as $thedata) {
                list($partno, $name, $description, $price, $image) = explode('|', $thedata);
                if ($partno == $varname) {
                    $myFile = "purchases.txt";
                    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("ERROR: Failed to open purchases file!\n");
                    $content = $now . "|" . $visitor . "|" . $partno . "|" . $name . "|" . $price . "\n";

                    if (!(fwrite($fh, $content))) {
                        echo "<p>ERROR: Cannot write to file($myFile)\n</p>";
                        exit;
                    } else {
                        $count++;
                        fclose($fh);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    if ($count>0)
        echo "<p>Order Submitted! $count Times</p>";
```